# Dynamic Removal of Multiple Form Options in Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google form where individuals are to enter in their employer preference and then a time for that employer. I currently have a script that is supposed to function where the form is updated to eliminate options after certain thresholds are reached. However, even when using the form with one option, it does not function correctly.

So, I have two questions here:

1) How do I get this type of action to occur in the form without utilizing the provided Google apps formLimiter and Choice Eliminator?

Here is the script code I was using:

```
function availableSlots()
{

    var form = FormApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdLRI6BmDXdCCygpHMr7o8MtnYLEVdrnumoHJfW-j_uTZCNiA/viewform?usp=sf_link');
    var slots = SpreadsheetApp
        .getActiveSpreadsheet()
        .getRange("Sheet2!A7:C10")  
        .getValues();

    var choice = [];
    {
        if (slots[s][0] != "" && slots[s][2] > 0) { 
            choice.push(slots[s][0]);
        }
    }
    var formItems = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST);
    formItems[0].asListItem().setChoiceValues(choice); 
}
```

2) Is there a way for the code to check for not only if the employer has been met by the max amount of respondents - because of all times being chosen already - and relay a message to the respondent that this employer is booked, but also behave in a way where if one time is taken for one employer, only that time is taken away if that employer was selected?

Comment: Try this - https://www.pbainbridge.co.uk/2019/04/dynamically-remove-google-form-options.html